# IPFS/Nginx Port 2001

Tags: ipfs

I have been resolving issues related to IPFS access and it seems the design is that 127.0.0.1 is used for local updates with an API interface to a app. I have 5001 access issues and I have checked already IPFS CORS.

Here is the error -

```
POST http://jenbil.com:5001/api/v0/cat?arg=QmU5KhkgvweYgE3Gsr8A19uFQrq7mszx7dubcoo89cTmAV&stream-channels=true net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I have this config -

```
{
  "API": {
    "HTTPHeaders": {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": [
        "true"
      ],
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": [
        "PUT",
        "POST",
        "GET"
      ],
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": [
        "*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "Addresses": {
    "API": "/ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/5001",
    "Gateway": "/ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/8180",
    "Swarm": [
      "/ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/4001",
      "/ip6/::/tcp/4001"
    ]
  },
  "Bootstrap": [
    "/ip4/104.131.131.82/tcp/4001/ipfs/QmaCpDMGvV2BGHeYERUEnRQAwe3N8SzbUtfsmvsqQLuvuJ",


    "/ip6/2604:a880:1:20::1d9:6001/tcp/4001/ipfs/QmSoLju6m7xTh3DuokvT3886QRYqxAzb1kShaanJgW36yx"
  ],
   "Datastore": {
     "BloomFilterSize": 0,
     "GCPeriod": "1h",
     "HashOnRead": false,
     "NoSync": false,
     "Params": null,
     "Path": "/root/.ipfs/datastore",
     "StorageGCWatermark": 90,
     "StorageMax": "10GB",
     "Type": "leveldb"
   },
   "Discovery": {
     "MDNS": {
       "Enabled": true,
       "Interval": 10
     }
   },
   "Experimental": {
     "FilestoreEnabled": false,
     "ShardingEnabled": false
   },
   "Gateway": {
     "HTTPHeaders": {
       "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": [
         "X-Requested-With"
       ],
       "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": [
         "GET"
       ],
       "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": [
         "*"
       ]
     },
     "PathPrefixes": [],
"RootRedirect": "",
     "Writable": false
   },
   "Identity": {
     "PeerID": "QmNwbtyFuEBDoB2BQGNe144jJXGJPJ9QrcwzNDMuqGYiZ9"
   },
   "Ipns": {
     "RecordLifetime": "",
     "RepublishPeriod": "",
     "ResolveCacheSize": 128
   },
   "Mounts": {
     "FuseAllowOther": false,
     "IPFS": "/ipfs",
     "IPNS": "/ipns"
   },
   "Reprovider": {
     "Interval": "12h"
   },
   "SupernodeRouting": {
     "Servers": null
   },
   "Swarm": {
     "AddrFilters": null,
     "DisableBandwidthMetrics": false,
     "DisableNatPortMap": false
   },
   "Tour": {
     "Last": ""
   }
```

And the config file for Nginx

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
listen 8080;
listen 5001;
listen 8180;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

#   root /usr/share/nginx/html/ipfs/src;
#
root /usr/share/nginx/html;
#root /var/www/html;
index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
#   index App.js index.html index.htm;
#listen   443 ssl;
server_name jenbil.com;
#server_name _;
#ssl    on;
#ssl_certificate    /home/keys/jenbil.com.chained.crt;
#ssl_certificate_key    /home/keys/jenbil.key;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
###jenbil   server_name localhost;

    location / {
```

Comment: I mean 5001 of course.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the problem, but it might be an issue with port collisions. Try using something unused, like :15001 and :18080 for ports in the IPFS config (bound to localhost only), and use 5001 and 8080/8180 in nginx redirecting them to the 1xxxx port counterparts.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do with this request to IPFS?

`cat` is a read operation, so you should use the HTTP GET action, not POST, with `/api/v0/cat`.

Comment: Have you any code example? I cannot even see where GET is specified.

Comment: Browsers, curl and most HTTP client libraries use HTTP `GET` by default. There are many examples of how to use the IPFS HTTP API at https://ipfs.io/docs/api/  They all use [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/), which you can treat as a stand-in for whichever client library you choose. The specific documentation for the `cat` command is at https://ipfs.io/docs/api/#apiv0cat

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the IPFS host to `0.0.0.0`

```
ipfs config Addresses.API /ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/5001
ipfs config Addresses.Gateway /ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/9001
```

You may also need to set CORS:

```
ipfs config --json API.HTTPHeaders.Access-Control-Allow-Origin '["*"]'
```

Restart IPFS daemon.